# How do I get a Priority Queue to re-sort itself

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a Priority Queue that keeps track of a list of employees and the comparator it uses to sort in the beginning sorts them by there current "Invite Value". So I want to pick the max invite value Employee, invite him and then re-pick the next max invite value employee. The tricky part is that after I invite a certain employee, it effects the invite value of some other employees in the list. I've tried the following

```
PriorityQueue<Employee> leafs = new PriorityQueue<>();
//populating the queue happens here

while(!leafs.isEmpty()){

Employee maxLeaf = leafs.peek();
        int maxValue = maxLeaf.getInviteValue();

        maxLeaf.invite();
        totalValue += maxValue;
        k--;

        for(Employee e : leafs){
            if(e.invValueChanged){
                leafs.remove(e);
                leafs.add(e);
            }
        }
}
```

Each employee will know if it's value needs to be recalculated based on the last invite by looking at it's invValueChanged field. This code is giving me an error with the Priority Queue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.PriorityQueue$Itr.next(PriorityQueue.java:535)
```

Comment: Take 'em all out. Put 'em all back in. A `PriorityQueue` is not sorted.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That would take too long. I'm using a priority queue to make it more efficient. Is there some structure that would be better for this?

Comment: _That would take too long_ That's exactly what you are currently doing, but you're doing it incorrectly. You can't structurally change a data structure on which you're iterating.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, that you need to change other elements in the data structure.

You cannot just iterate over them, and do operations on them, this will change the ordering of elements.

The best way to do this, is to create a vector of the current structure, do operations on the vector, and reinsert them.

If speed is what troubles you, this operations have the same time complexity as the code you wrote.

Inserting an element in a priority queue, takes O(log(n)) time, you do that n times, so you get O(n log (n)) time.

Making a vector from a priory queue takes O(n), time. Inserting all elements in the priority queue from the vector, takes O(n log(n)) time.

So the speed should be asymptotically the same.
The real speed should also be very close.